# Histogram of Sums from Categorical/Binary Data

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I wanted a graphical and attractive way to represent column sums for binary data rather than a tabular format. I can't seem to get it to work, though one would think it would be a lay-up.

The data look like this (I tried creating a reproducible example, but couldn't get the code to populate with 0s and 1s).

```
G1 G2 G3 G4
1  0  0  1
0  1  1  1
1  1  0  0
0  1  0  1
```

I just want to count up (sum) the 1s in each column, display the group names along the x-axis, the counts (sums) along the y-axis, and make the bars pretty colours. I have tried every solution on here and many that are not.

Comment: Try `barplot(colSums(df1))`

Comment: Try: `df %>% 
  gather(key,val) %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  summarise(Sum=sum(val)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(key,Sum,fill=key))+geom_col()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `tidyverse` approach:

```
 library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  gather(key,val) %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  summarise(Sum=sum(val)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(key,Sum,fill=key))+geom_col()
```

Or as suggested by @akrun :

```
df %>% summarise_all(sum)
 %>% gather %>%
 ggplot(., aes(x = key, y = value)) + 
geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Or another approach i `summarise_all`, `gather` `df %>% summarise_all(sum) %>% gather %>% ggplot(., aes(x = key, y = value)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`

Comment: Wow! Ok, I guess it's time to learn tidyverse or dplyr or the like. I should have asked this yesterday!

Answer (score 3):

As the values are binary, simply do the `colSums` in `base R` and then use `barplot`

```
barplot(colSums(df1), col = c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow"))
```

[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(G1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), G2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    G3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), G4 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Certainly worked! was using ggplot2, but I'm cool with the base package. Just need a bit more granularity on the y axis, but I can look that up.